# How to store custome user login credentials in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an existing users database so I don't use the .NET user profile things that come out-of-the box.

I have a controller where I implemented functionalities for create user, retrieve password, register users, view etc. The only question is, how can I pass the user login credentials (such as user id, login time, roles etc) across the web application so that it can be used as a mean of security access for certain pages? For example only users with admin role can access certain page.

Should I pass it as session object?

Comment: In `Session` object??

Comment: Yeah but is that a good way of storing it? Is there better way? I am trying to avoid the membership thingy and to make it much simpler.

Comment: Have some kind of user credentials class, where you can collect all the info you want and let the session have a property of that class which will be set after successful login. How much more simple can you get? No membership thingy whatsoever.

Comment: I guess that's what @Paritosh meant, too.

Comment: @Corak: yes(+1).. After successful login, store required parameters in `Session`. as simple as that. On logout, set it to `null`

Comment: Just a quick question. I feel like I would be better designing my own account management (for page accesses etc) than using .net membership which I can never understand (I understand how to use it but to make it work with my existing db is just PIA). Is there any flaw in this approach? I am using .NET MVC4 fyi

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.Net membership provider to specify access for different roles or users.

To require users to login, use:

```
[Authorize]
public class YourController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize]
public ActionResult YourAction()
```

To restrict access for specific roles, use:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public class SomeController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

And to restrict access for specific users, use:

```
[Authorize(Users = "ABC1, ABC2")]
public class SomeController : Controller

// Or
[Authorize(Users = "ABC1, ABC2")]
public ActionResult SomeAction()
```

For more please have a look on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/288631/Secure-ASP-NET-MVC3-applications

Please feel free to ask further specific question. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to follow the guideline on every tutorial I ran across on how to create custom membership from existing db but it is always complicated for me to understand.

Comment: Yes it need little learning curve...so just have patience and enjoy...I hope below article would help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/280129/Extending-Asp-Net-role-based-Security-with-Custom  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use forms authentication for starters: [ASP.NET Forms Authentication Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Save the database user id on it.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userId, rememberMe);
```

With that you can always get the user id. Then its up to you to either get the user details when you need them using the user id. If you need this all the time, cache it on the Session object. In any case, use forms authentication because even if the session dies, you can always get the user id again from the forms autentication and rebuild its cache. Another advantage of using forms authentication is that if you are on a web farm, you have got a session object per web server, but since the user id is always available on the auth cookie, you can always get it.